# ajax link in script tag

Tags: html, asp.net-ajax

i've made a webpage where i used a code that i found on the internet. in this code is a link to an ajax page. I uploaded my html and css to a webserver, now i get a message "this website is trying to load unverified sources". is it possible to copy this code to a file and add this this to my webserver, so the message doesn't appear? thanks in advance.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just copy jquery.min.js to local folder and update script source to point local JavaScript jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a security issue.

Try like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enjoy.